# The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud platform but I succeed to build and deploy a simple page on Cloud run. Then I tried to do it with this git 'https://github.com/bnkamalesh/htmlhost' and I am stuck with this error :

> Revision 'stp-container-00001-wtr' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable

I ran it "locally" on Cloud shell and it worked fine but once I build and push it to my repository with Cloud run, I'm getting the error. I defined the PORT as 8000, I tried with 8080 but still not working.

What would explain that I succeed to make it work locally but not with Cloud run.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 redis:
 image: redis
 restart: always

htmlhost:
 container_name: stp-container
 image: stp-image
 build:
  dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
  context: .
  restart: always
  env_file: 
   - ./docker/.htmlhost.env
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
   - redis
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine3.15 AS builder

COPY ${PWD} /app-src
WORKDIR /app-src

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -mod=vendor -ldflags '-s -w -extldflags "-static"' -o /app/htmlhost *.go
COPY internal/server/http/web /app/internal/server/http/web

FROM alpine:3.15
LABEL MAINTAINER Kamaleshwar <bnkamalesh@gmail.com>

# Run as a non-root/non-privileged user
RUN adduser -D appuser
USER appuser

COPY --from=builder /app /home/appuser/app

WORKDIR /home/appuser/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./htmlhost"]
```

My htmlhost.env

```
HTTP_PORT=8080
DATASTORE_HOST=redis
```

I don't understand what is going on

Comment: Docker compose does not work on Cloud Run. But you have now the sidecar feature that allow you to do the same! https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing this as community wiki for other's sake.

as mentioned by @Guillaume Blaquiere

---

> Docker compose does not work on Cloud Run. But you have now the sidecar feature that allow you to do the same! [Cloud Run now supports sidecar deployments — monitoring agents, proxies and more](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments)

---

Other reference that might help:

- [Local development for Cloud Run with Docker Compose](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-local-dev-docker-compose)